# Are rewards in reinforcement learning scale and shift invariant?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Say I have a reinforcement learning environment with a reward function $f$, and hypothesizing that there is a single best policy, can we state that the final policy is the same for all the functions in the class:
$$
r = c \cdot f,\,\,\,\, c \in \mathbb{R+}\\
or\\
r = c + f,\,\,\,\, c \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Example:
given a game, having a reward function that gives +1 if you win and -1 if you lose, if it's the same of having 0 for loss and 2 for win and so on

Comment: Maximising the expected reward should produce the same result with location and scale changes since $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$ and you have $a>0$

Comment: @Henry thus if for some reason my algorithm have some problem with negative rewards, i can just add a constant enough not to have anymore negative rewards, right? (btw, thank you so much for the answer)

Comment: If you are maximising the expected reward then it should not make a difference.  But if instead for example you are maximising the expectation of the logarithm of the reward (a possibility if negative rewards break the algorithm) then it may not work